# Email with Inbox / Outbox single app using ember js

Tags: javascript, email, ember.js, handlebars.js, mustache

I've recently (2 days ago) come across a simple email system built in ember js, but I can't seem to find it anymore!

it was just a single page app written in ember js (i think!!)

Comment: Did you run through this list, http://emberjs.com/ember-users/, to see if any of the companies rang a bell?

Comment: not really.. this was a simple one page app with a left navigation
Inbox
Outbox
etc.

Comment: it wasnt a company per say.. it was just an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scroll down a bit (to **Routing**) on http://emberjs.com/, I think that's the one you meant.